# In the market or to the market?

Tags: prepositions

“A new brand is introduced *in* the market” or “A new product is introduced *to* the market”? Which one is correct? Thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: Why should only one be correct? The context will determine which preposition is needed. Even without further broader context, it is fine to use either preposition.

Comment: @Fattie Even that.

Answer (score 22):

Both work, but the connotation is slightly different. One is **where** is it introduced, the other is **whereto** is it introduced.

**Introducing in the market:**

```
|==============================|
|     MARKET                   |
|                              |
|                wow           |
|               O              |
| look at      /|\             |
| my thing     / \      so     |
|   O__▣               O cool  |
|  /|         such    /|\      |
|  / \       O thing  / \      |
|           /|\                |
|           / \                |
|                              |
|==============================|
```

**Introducing to the market:**

```
            |==============================|
            |     MARKET                   |
            |                              |
            |         wow                  |
            |       O                      |
            |      /|\                     |
            |      / \            so       |
look at     |                    O cool    |
my thing    |           such    /|\        |
  O__▣      |         O thing   / \        |
 /|         |        /|\                   |
 / \        |        / \                   |
            |                              |
            |==============================|
```

Comment: Heh - perfect - but introducing it "to" the market is different from introducing it into the market.

Comment: Speaking of "connotation", "look at my thing" almost always has a rather specific one, at least in Am.E. - something most would NOT say in a marketplace...  :)

Comment: @mendota While light hearted, it wasn't meant (strictly) as a joke.  It was simply meant to inform those for whom, as non-native speakers, may not otherwise be aware of the "my thing" connotation.  Maybe I should have been more explicit.  So, thanks for making the point clearer.  Now, I do have to admit, as native AmE speaker, I had to look up "doge-speak", and I still can't say I totally get it. Although that may say more about "my generation"... :)

Comment: Please cite a source.

Comment: @Max Vollmer, excellent.

Answer (score 9):

In this context, “to” would be the correct preposition. “In the market” would connote that something was introduced in a marketplace, as opposed to something being put on the market. An alternative to *to* would be *into*. “A new brand is introduced **into** the market.” Something or someone has to be introduced ***to*** something or someone else. You can’t *introduce in* or *introduce on*.

Comment: No problem. I hope I was helpful.

Comment: Yup. It was helpful indeed.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but interesting that searching for some other prepositions in Google ("new X the market") shows that "on" is used for property (in the UK, at least) and "in" is used for companies.

Comment: @JamesRandom Well, you have to introduce something or someone *to* something or someone else. You can say—in America as well—that a new item is *on* the market. For instance, “A new phone is **on** the market” is more idiomatic than “A new phone is **in** the market.”

Comment: "Hypothesis 7: The rate at which drug products are **introduced to the market** will first increase, then decrease with the number of products **introduced in the market**"  https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YrpXDkKUZzkC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22introduced+in+the+market%22+%22introduced+to+the+market%22&source=bl&ots=lrN176eTNM&sig=8w1XAJoWldHntoP54LIDa9ad1j8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKxrqDtrfcAhVHX30KHdxKBcgQ6AEwAnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22introduced%20in%20the%20market%22%20%22introduced%20to%20the%20market%22&f=false

Comment: -1 Please cite your sources.

Comment: @Kris In "The rate at which drug products are introduced to the market", introduced" is the past participle of "introduce" used to form the passive voice version of the verb. In " number of products introduced in the market", "introduced" is an adjective.

Comment: @Kris I assume you have a point?

Answer (score 2):

Consider omitting any explicit reference to the market.

Example 1.
“A new brand is introduced to the market when a company wants to target a new demographic.”

vs.

“A new brand is introduced when a company wants to target a new demographic.”

Example 2.
“When a new product is introduced to the market it falls to advertisers and early adopters to inform the public.”

vs.

“When a new product is introduced it falls to advertisers and early adopters to inform the public.”